# Vb want to cut off decimal number at 1 place

Tags: vb.net

So I have a double that is 123.778967. I want it to be returned as 123.7.
Everything I have read and tried always rounds, so im getting 123.8 because it is rounding up. So can someone tell me how I just cut the numbers I dont want off?

Comment: multiply by 10, floor, divide by 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this as an extension method before:

```
''' <summary>
''' Truncate the provided decimal value to the provided number of decimal places.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="ToTruncate">The number to be truncated.</param>
''' <param name="NumberOfPlaces">The number of decimal places at which the number will be truncated.</param>
''' <returns>The provided number, truncated to the provided number of decimal places.</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Function TruncateDecimal(ByVal toTruncate As Decimal, ByVal numberOfPlaces As Integer) As Decimal
    Dim temp = (10 ^ numberOfPlaces)
    Return CDec(Fix(toTruncate * temp) / temp)
End Function
```